# Simple application that serves files over http with authentication

Tags: file-server

Is there a simple application that will serve files over http (with a simple web interface/directory listing) with authentication? I am going to setup a home server based on a SBC (think Raspberry Pi like) and was wondering if such an application existed as a lightweight, simple alternative to Owncloud. I could then take care of the syncing myself by using rsync or BitTorrent Sync.

Comment: Why not use apache? It does not take that much resources.

Comment: Can Apache do that? Pardon my ignorance, I don't know much about web servers ;)

Comment: Sure it can, and there's plenty of tutorials and docs for it.

Comment: I second that, Apache would be just fine.

Comment: Would Apache also allow uploading? Also how secure is basic HTTP authentication?

Comment: ahh, didn't see this before my answer below. Uploading is a bit more complicated, but could be done with an additional Nginx module. Here are two examples, one uploading using curl (https://coderwall.com/p/swgfvw/nginx-direct-file-upload-without-passing-them-through-backend) and another that has part of a form for posting (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Uploading-to-nginx-using-the-nginx-upload-module-with-php_handler)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am also considering writing my own little script with NodeJS, although the dealing with sessions part seems to be complicated. The GitHub link involves PHP, that is a large downside, because I have zero experience with PHP, while I at least have some experience with JS and have played with NodeJS a bit. Curl won't work either, because the whole reason I want a web interface is to be able to access my files on systems that I don't own and have no control over.

Answer (score 0):

You could use any web server for http content list and basic authentication. Basic authentication is secure, but you should be sending it over an SSL tunnel. For your home system, self-signed certificates will likely suffice to protect authentication requests. I would recommend lighttp or nginx if you are using embeded hardware because process based web servers (apache in default configuration) will use more resources for each connection. The main difference between lightty and nginx is that lightty uses a single process and a single non-blocking thread and nginx uses a master process to delegate work to children processes.

Here is an example `/etc/nginx.conf` (no tested, so may need some tweaking). You would simply need to create a folder at /etc/nginx/tls and add a self-signed SSL keypair to it (cert.pem, cert.key).

```
user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;
events {
  worker_connections  64;
}
http {
  default_type      application/octet-stream;
  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  access_log        var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
  keepalive_timeout 60;
  server {
    server_name                 localhost;
    listen                      80 443;
    ssl                         on;
    ssl_certificate             tls/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key         tls/cert.key;
    ssl_session_timeout         5m;
    ssl_protocols               TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers                 HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    location / {
      root   /path/to/your/data;
      autoindex on;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have also been looking at WebDAV, it seems that doesn't have a web interface either, but Windows Explorer apparently supports WebDAV (the computers which I would like to able to access my files from run Windows) so that might be an option, that would also support uploading.

Comment: WebDAV works amazingly great and it fairly simple to setup. It's been a few years since I have, but it's likely not any more complicated than it was back then.

Comment: Okay, that's great to hear, if all goes well, the power adapter for my ARM board should arrive today, so I will finally be able to turn it on for the first time :)